# Why does my image extend past my wrapper?

Tags: html, css, image, wrapper

I'm starting on a website for my portfolio for a class, and my header image is going out past the wrapper? I can't seem to get it to move back to the left. (nameheader img)

I want it the same width as the document, which is 1050px wide.
[This is what it keeps doing... that little gray square on the top right is where the wrapper starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh6Du.jpg)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sarah's Portfolio</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

      <div id="header">
        <div id=nameheader">
          <img src="images/nameheader.png" alt="header" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="nav">
        <a href="#"> HOME </a>
        <a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a>
        <a href="#"> ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#"> CONTACT </a>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color:#000000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1050px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#E4E5E6;

}

#header {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('WebFont.eot');
    src: url('WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}

#nav {
    width: 1050px;
    height: 54.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#000000;
    font-family: 'MyWebFont', Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 13px
}

#nameheader img {
    width: 1050px;
    height: 485px;
    display: block;
}


#content {
    width:0px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to make a background for your body tag?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a quote in your div tag for your nameheader which is probably breaking your page.

Answer (score 2):

Also need to update the image's parent container's width/height:

```
#header {
  width: 0px; <-- here
  height: 0px; <-- here
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

To save you some trouble in the future if your page width changes, would also recommend changing to:

```
#nameheader img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 485px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`#nameheader img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 485px;
    display: block;
}`

Your wrapper is already of `1050px` so there is no need to again provide the width to image. Let it inherit from its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:hidden; to the div that contains the image.